# How to make OnMButtonDblClk work in Windows ce 6.0?

Tags: windows-ce

i have added following coe in my view class but still it's not working.

```
BOOL CtestView::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
  if (CView::PreCreateWindow(cs))
  {
     WNDCLASS wc;
     // Get the class information for the default MFC view class.
     ::GetClassInfo(AfxGetInstanceHandle(),cs.lpszClass,&wc);

     // Register a new class using the attributes of the default
     // view class, and make it the new default class.
     cs.lpszClass = AfxRegisterWndClass(wc.style | CS_DBLCLKS,
        wc.hCursor,wc.hbrBackground,wc.hIcon);
     return TRUE;
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your window set to receive double click events? See this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms924833.aspx). Quote:

> An application-defined window does
>   not, by default, receive double-click
>   messages. Because of the system
>   overhead involved in generating
>   double-click messages, these messages
>   are generated only for windows
>   belonging to classes that have the
>   CS_DBLCLKS class style. Your
>   application must set this style when
>   registering the window class.

You can also create your own double-clicks by managing up/down events, the delta between the cursor locations of those events and the time between them.

So for example, this sequence:

- Down message (save control)
- start timer
- less than 250 milliseconds passed
- up message (on same control)
- less than 250 milliseconds
- Down message (on same control)
- less than 250 milliseconds
- up message (on same control)

= double click

If in that sequence your timeout expires or the control changes you reset your counters and variables since the action was not a double click.

Comment: i have added the code as mention aboce in my question. but still its not working

Comment: @Suri: Strange. You can also create your own double-clicks by managing up/down events, the delta between the cursor locations of those events and the time between them. Se  my edited answer above.

Comment: OnMButtonDblClick is not working but OnLButtonDblClick is working well.

Comment: That makes sense. MButton means `M`iddle button which doesn't surprise me that it would not be suported on CE.